# in wxpython show and hide frames

Tags: model-view-controller, wxpython, show-hide, publish-subscribe

I try to work with the mvc-model. I use pubsub to communicate between the different files. I use wxpython to build the gui of my program.

I open in my main file 2 frames: filter_view (main class of this file) and MA_view (I import this as a module):

```
    maview = MA_view.Main(None) 
    maview.Hide()
```

I hide MA_view, because I just need it to be open so I can use pubsub to communicate. Now, when a user wants to open MA_view in the menubar in filter_view, I don't want to open a new MA_view, I just want to show the hided frame.

The problem is that the menubar of the filter_view is also in a separate file so when I type

```
maview.Show()
```

of course it doesn't now maview because in this file it is not defined. But when I define it like this:

```
maview = MA_view.Main(None)
```

It just opens a new frame.

I really don't like working with mvc (probably because my programming skills aren't good enough) but I'm working with other collegues, so I have to work this way.

tx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is super important so hang in there, you won't regret the extra learning curve. Here are the steps that use wx.lib.pubsub to support MVC on your app:

1. In both files, add `from wx.lib.pubsub import pub`.
2. In the `MA_view` module, make the `Main.__init__` subscribe to a topic that will tell the `Main` instance to unhide itself, like    `pub.subscribe('unhide_ma', self.__unhide)`.
3. In the `filter_view` file, send a message from menubar handler like `pub.sendMessage('unhide_ma')`.
4. In the `Main.__unhide`, you unhide the window.

Comment: tx for the peptalk :o) I actually enjoy the learning curve, but sometimes it is soooo frustrating ;o) But thanks for the help, it works!! I'm so happy!